# pandas column consists of list with longer elements to_sql

Tags: mysql, pandas, list

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sqlalchemy.types import (Integer, SMALLINT, Float, Boolean, DateTime,
                                      Date, TIMESTAMP, VARCHAR, NVARCHAR, TEXT)
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql://root@localhost/db?charset=utf8', encoding = 'utf-8')

a = pd.DataFrame({'you': [1,2,3, 4, 5], 'me': [[635257640452, 276186475296, '087454447714', '045122406667', 406921512703, 781214103164, '070255969253'],[123],[456],[789], []]})

a.to_sql(con=engine, name='raw_data', if_exists='append', index=False, dtype = {'you': Integer, 'me' : TEXT})
```

I want to put a dataframe into the mysql database. But the df consist of multiple columns that are like the 'me' column.
So a list, that can be empty or filled with multiple different elements. 
I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Why not join with a separator and save a single comma separated string?

Comment: I am not sure if i understand your comment, but the number of list elements is not constant, so separation would leed to sparse columns.

Comment: My suggestion is `a['me'] = a['me'].map(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x)))` before saving. Later, when you need to read your data, use `a['me'] = a['me'].str.split(',')` .

Comment: Thank you, this is a workaround that works. If there are other solutions I would be still interested to see.